# Configure Vue CLI to use external libraries and source-maps devtools

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I would like to configure my Vue CLI to use external library and source-maps in order to debug my application.

I found those two `vue.config.js` samples for external libs.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.externals({ jquery: 'jQuery', bootstrap: 'bootstrap' });
  }
};
```

and  and for devtools.

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

How can I join those both configurations?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the approach below?

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.externals({ jquery: 'jQuery', bootstrap: 'bootstrap' });
        config.merge({ devtool: 'source-map' });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for asset size limit warning for my Vue app, and config.merge did the trick for me, thanks @john craft